# how to reach components in macrocomponent by id?

Tags: zk

I have a zul file (*MainPage.zul*) which contains a macrocomponent (*configtabs*). Macrocomponent's zul file inturn contains another macrocomponent(*fieldListBox*). How can I use the id of second macrocomponent(*fieldListBox*) in my MainPage's Controller class? I want to set model for second macrocomponent in doAfterCompose method of MainPage's cOntroller class.

**Example code:**

```
<?component name="configtabs" macro-uri="iam.configtab.zul" ?> 
<zk>
  <window>
    <configtabs />
  </window>
</zk>
```

configtab.zul

```
<hbox>
  <fieldListBox id="fieldsbox" />
</hbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zk selectors for that.
[Click here for a little bit of explanation of what are those selectors.](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVC/Controller/Wire_Components)

Also every component [has query methods](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/7.0.1/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Component.html#query%28java.lang.String%29). If you use those methods with the selectors you can query for components inside other components. It's been very useful to me. 
For example on your doAfterCompose you can do:

```
configtabs.queryAll("fieldListBox")
```

Or

```
configtabs.queryAll("#fieldsbox")
```

And it returns the component or components that you want to set model.
I hope it's helpful. It depends on the context.